# Error with cx_Freeze and xlwings as standalone version with fibonacci tutorial

Tags: python-2.7, cx-freeze, xlwings

When I compile the example fibonacci from xlwings as a standalone version, I get the following error upon execution.
I have tried to include files using the `include_files` option in the cx_Freeze setup script but I keep getting the error.

Has someone any idea on how to correct that problem ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in     <module>
  File "ioforge.py", line 10, in <module>

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlwings-0.3.0-py2.7.egg\xlwings\__init__.py",     line 18, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlwings-0.3.0-py2.7.egg\xlwings\_xlwindows.py",     line 9, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 123] Syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume     incorrecte: ''
```

The line on which is the problem is as below :

```
# Hack to find pythoncom.dll - needed for some distribution/setups
# E.g. if python is started with the full path outside of the python path, then it almost     certainly fails
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(sys.exec_prefix)
import win32api
os.chdir(cwd)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It complains that it doesn't find your directories. Try to uninstall/reinstall xlwings completely (if necessary check in the `Anaconda\Lib\site-packages` folder. `xlwings-0.3.0-py2.7.egg` is usually called `xlwings-0.3.0-py2.7.egg-info` so not sure if that is the reason it doesn't find it.

Comment: I reinstalled xlwings but the problem is still identic although the link is now "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py"

Comment: The pasted lines where it fails actually makes sense. I've opened an issues on GitHub: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/133

Comment: A workaround is to comment the 9th line of the _xlwindows.py and copy all the folders inside Lib/site-packages in the build/exe-2.7.

Comment: The issue has been fixed and should be available in the next version (v0.3.3) - you should not have to copy files from the site-packages folder manually.